# Passing data between controllers via a parameter in the URL - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So, I'm building an Angular web app currently, and am now trying to get my head around the basics of building routes and views.

In my DashboardCtrl, I have my spartaCustomers array, where I store some information about my clients.

In my dashboard view, I build a basic table and spit out the information. As you can see, I link from the Client in each row to a new /client page and pass the id into the URL.

**What I need help with**

In my ClientCtrl below, I want to fetch the client object from the array from the DashboardCtrl so I can use it on the /client view. I successfully fetch the client id from the URL, but have not yet figured out how to "look up" the client information from the first controller.

Any help would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
<table class="table">
    <th>Client id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Contract Length</th>
    <th>Current Contract Value</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Next Renewal Date</th>
    <th>MRR</th>

    <tr ng-repeat="c in spartaCustomers">
        <td>{{c.id}}</td>
        <td><a href="/#/client/{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{c.currentContractLength}}</td>
        <td>{{c.currentContractValue}}</td>
        <td>{{c.startDate}}</td>
        <td>{{c.endDate}}</td>
        <td>{{c.nextRenewalDate}}</td>
        <td>{{c.mrr}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first controller:

```
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.spartaCustomers = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "John Inc",
        currentContractLength: 12,
        currentContractValue: 18000,
        startDate: "09/01/2014",
        endDate: "09/01/2015",
        nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2015",
        mrr: 1500

    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Peters Company Ltd",
        currentContractLength: 3,
        currentContractValue: 15000,
        startDate: "09/01/2014",
        endDate: "09/01/2015",
        nextRenewalDate: "09/01/2015",
        mrr: 1500
    }]

)};
```

My "client" controller:

```
angular.module('atlantisApp')
  .controller('ClientCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter) {
    $scope.clientId = $routeParams.clientId; //This works and fetches the id 

    //fetch the client object here for use inside this controller

  });
```

Comment: I would make the app as steteless as possible, and get the client data from the a web service, to make sure you're displaying the latest values, and not some stale data cached in a service for 5 hours. It would also be much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use service to share data between controllers. below is just an example

```
app.factory('theService', function() {  
    return {
        customers: {}
    };
});

app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, theService) {
    theService.customers = $scope.customers;
});

app.controller("ClientCtrl", function($scope, theService) { 
    $scope.customers = theService.customers; 
});
```

or you can get data from server per customer id which would keep controllers independent of each other.

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense! One question though, should I just store this service in the main app.js controller?

Comment: @user2656127: think about what happens if the user hits the refresh button of his browser when on the client page...

Comment: no, i used `app` just for example, you should keep it inside your module.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I can make progress with this!